# Are there performance issues when using both an EntityManager and Spring Repository in the same transacation?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a case where my `Foo` contains an object `Bar`, and if that `Bar` object does not already exist in the `BarRepository`, I want to persist it first and then continue to save the `Foo` object (don't need to do this when first creating the Foo object, but for some reason need to do this when updating it with a new Bar object).

I am wondering if it is either considered bad practice or any significant performance issues when combining both the an `EntityManager` (to update) and a Spring Repository (to check if something exists) together.

Here is my particular case:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooService {

  private final FooRepository fooRepository;
  private final BarRepository barRepository;
  private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  // works fine
  public Foo update(long id, Consumer<Foo> consumer) {
    var foo = get(id);
    updateFields(foo, consumer);
    var entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    var transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    if (foo.getBar() != null) {
      if (!barRepository.existsById(foo.getBar().getId())) {// option 1
        entityManager.persist(foo.getBar());
      }
    }
    var update = entityManager.merge(foo);
    transaction.commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return update;
  }

  // doesnt work yet, but the idea is this
  public Foo update(long id, Consumer<Foo> consumer) {
    var foo = get(id);
    updateFields(foo, consumer);
    var entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    var transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    if (foo.getBar() != null) {
      var barId = foo.getBar().getId();
      if (entityManager // option 2
              .createNativeQuery(
                      "SELECT b FROM bar b WHERE b.text = ?1 AND b.duration = ?2")
              .setParameter(1, barId.getText()())
              .setParameter(2, barId.getDuration())
              .getSingleResult()
              == null) {
        entityManager.persist(foo.getBar());
      }
    }
    var update = entityManager.merge(foo);
    transaction.commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return update;
  }

}
```

Out of these two methods, to me the first one is much cleaner to me because the checking of the the `Foo` entity is a small, one liner, compared to the other one, but I want to follow whatever the standard is.

Comment: Isn't it messy to use two large framework at the same time? Both are on their own capable.

Comment: Since you're using Sping Data JPA the respository will be using the entity manager internally anyway. In order to keep things more orderly and maintainable why don't you do it all via the Spring repository?

Comment: @Thomas I originally was trying to do it that way actually, however, I couldn't get the update for the nested Bar object to work correctly. But in that case, I should revisit the original issue and fix it accordingly.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I agree, it does seem a bit messy/too much to have both. Will try to stick with one then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data JPA is build on JPA and uses the `EntityManager` internally.
Spring Data never aimed at completely removing JPA from your code base. Its goal is to make the easy stuff trivial and comfortable while not getting in your way when you need to use it directly.

So using the `EntityManager` is completely fine and actually expected for many non trivial applications.

But code accessing the `EntityManager` lives on a different abstraction layer than the code using a repository.
I therefore recommend to move your `EntityManager` using code into [custom methods of your repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).